# Springboot 2 CrudRepository.save always throws ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have Migrated the Springboot version from 1.4.3.RELEASE to 2.1.0.RELEASE in my project. After that CrudRepository.save() always throws org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement.

This is what I can see in the Logs :

```
o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper[m: SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper[m: Duplicate entry '11' for key 'PRIMARY'
o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl[m: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

This is the entity I am trying to save.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "project_m")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name" , nullable = false)
    private String name;

    //other fields

}
```

Comment: "Duplicate entry '11' for key 'PRIMARY'" - Seems self-explanatory to me.

Comment: Yeah but using the older version of spring i have mentioned I can simply save this.

Comment: Are you saying, if you change the version to 1.4.3 and run the same code right now, it will run successfully ?

Comment: No i updated from 1.4.3 to 2

Comment: To rephrase the question:  if you revert *back* to 1.4.3, would this exact code work?

Comment: @Makoto : Yes, I just checked  using with my old build.

Comment: ...and you're *sure* you don't have a duplicate ID value of 11 in your database?

Comment: @Makoto Yes I have.The entity need to save having id as null. So when saving,  it have to generate next value in the sequence for id right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConstraintViolationException` occurred due to the fact that your primary key constraint for SQL database violates 
In SQL the primary key is a unique key to identify the record, the database will throw an exception when you trying to insert a  duplicate value to a primary column.
which in turn got by the hibernate and passed to your code and is the reason for this exception.

From Springboot 1.4.3.RELEASE to 2.1.0.RELEASE Hibernate version is updated from 5.0 to 5.3.

The way Hibernate interprets AUTO generation type has changed starting with Hibernate version 5.0

If you use `strategy="AUTO"`, Hibernate will generate a table called `hibernate_sequence` to provide the next number for the ID sequence. You may have forgotten to add the AutoIncrement feature to your table's PK.

Another way to fix is use following annotations with `strategy="AUTO"`

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
    strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, 
    generator="native"
)
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "native", 
    strategy = "native"
)
private Long id;
```

You may use generation strategy `strategy="IDENTITY"` to enforce using the AutoIncrement feature available in SQL and avoid creating a table.

Pls check [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-should-not-use-the-auto-jpa-generationtype-with-mysql-and-hibernate/) to get some more insights

Answer (score 3):

What has changed from Springboot 1.4.3.RELEASE to 2.1.0.RELEASE is the internal **Hibernate** version from **5.0** to **5.3**.

And what has changed in this is the way the SequenceGenerator works, which is used in case the strategy is GenerationType.AUTO (as is in your case).
[image]

Link to [hibernate migration doc here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.2/migration-guide.adoc).

More details on hibernate generation strategy [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-auto).

My guess is there are 2 parallel sessions inserting into this table, and both of them now share a local copy of the sequence number, which creates this collision. Not sure though!

My suggestion  would be to change the strategy to GenerationType.SEQUENCE and try.

Answer (score 1):

I got a workaround for this issue by setting a large value in `hibernate_sequence` table. I saw that the primary key value from the duplicate primary key error is generated from a table named `hibernate_sequence`.

When we set GenerationType.AUTO in the entity,Hibernate selects the generation strategy based on the Hibernate dialect. In older versions , Hibernate selected the `GenerationType.IDENTITY` as default for MySQL databases.

It now selects the `GenerationType.TABLE` which uses a database table to generate primary keys